# Подскажите модуль для вставки из буфера в Tkinter с русской раскладки

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Всем привет! как вы знаете в Tkinter нельзя вставить в поле Entry с русской раскладки комбинацией Ctrl+V, только с английской. Видел тут на англоязычной ветке решения, но они показались громоздкими. Ищу решение в виде модуля (желательно) или максимально короткое в дзене Python :)

Comment: так и поделитесь ссылками на решения

Comment: @vadim-vaduxa например https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082243/how-to-bind-ctrl-in-python-tkinter

Comment: а нет, тоже работает только в английской раскладке

Answer (score 1):

В общем разобрался, может кому поможет:
после Entry pack добавляем

```
переменнаяEntry.event_add('<<Paste>>', '<Control-igrave>')
```

igrave- это русская м. полный список тут https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/keysyms.htm
почему не Cyrillic_EM я так и не понял

Answer (score 1):

Давний совет не работает на python3.9.
Оставлю здесь свое решение, может еще кому пригодится.

```
from tkinter import *


class Application:
    def __init__(self):
        app = Tk()
        app.title('HelloWorld!'),
        app.geometry('400x300')
        app.bind("<Control-KeyPress>", self.keypress)

        txt = Text()
        txt.pack(fill='both', expand=True)        
        
        app.mainloop()

    @staticmethod
    def keypress(event):
        if event.keycode == 86:
            event.widget.event_generate('<<Paste>>')
        elif event.keycode == 67:
            event.widget.event_generate('<<Copy>>')
        elif event.keycode == 88:
            event.widget.event_generate('<<Cut>>')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Application()
```