# Почему с RUS раскладкой ctr+v и ctr+c не работает, а с ENG все работает?(Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

Почему с RUS раскладкой ctr+v or ctr+c не работает, а с ENG все работает? Как это можно реализовать с `Text` и `Entry` в python?

Comment: Это от OS зависит

Comment: У меня win 10 professional

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/722885/178576

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае используйте [Alt код](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4), чтобы узнать код буквы, а после чего используйте [данную страницу](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/keysyms.htm) где описаны сигналы в `tkinter`.
Ну а использование `<<Copy>> <<Past>>` я думаю вы [с прошлого вопроса поняли.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/814653/255866)
Используя ссылку из вики вы ищите букву которая вам нужно в данном случае буквы `с` и `м` которые из таблиц в вики присвоен `Alt-код` : `241` и `236` соответственно дальше идем на вторую ссылку где описаны все клавиши в `tkinter` не большими манипуляциями( в браузере `Ctr+F`) мы ищем по странице наш `Alt-код` :
`Название сигнала: ntilde, Alt-код: 241` это будет буква `c`
`Название сигнала: igrave, Alt-код: 236` это будет буква `м`
После чего мы можем использовать название сигналов с комбинацией `Control-Button` как указано ниже в примере `'<Control-igrave>'`

Пример:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Text, Entry

root = Tk()

e = Text(root)
e.pack()

e_1 = Entry(root)
e_1.pack()

root.event_add('<<Paste>>', '<Control-igrave>')
root.event_add("<<Copy>>", "<Control-ntilde>")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Я не совсем понял, можно по-подробнее пожалуйста?

Comment: `'<<Paste>>'` и `"<<Copy>>"` понял, остальное нет

Comment: @оаавирыыва я думаю понятно объяснил если что спрашивайте

Comment: Да понял, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Используйте Скан-коды клавиш. Они не зависят от раскладки, но зависят от состояния клавиши (нажата/отжата)

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего *ctrl + v* и *ctrl + c* в случаи ENG раскладки действительно *ctrl + v* и *ctrl + c*, а в случае RUS это уже *ctrl + м* и *ctrl + с* (русские буквы).

Это если я правильно понял вопрос.

Comment: Да, все верно.  Как решать такую проблему?

Comment: @оаавирыыва Но как это решается, я к сожалению не знаю.